# how to remove error while calling server request

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am getting this error while calling the webservice request .I am using  restangular.js file .I am tring to call  webservice .But While calling webservice I am getting error .could you please help me remov

Here is my code

http://goo.gl/tbVgkY

I am reading the documentation from here
https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#element-methods

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.3/$injector/nomod?p0=app
    angular.min.js:101 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.3/ng/areq?p0=IndexCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
        at Error (native)
        at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js:6:416
        at Ob (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js:19:417)
        at pb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js:20:1)
        at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js:75:177
        at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js:57:112
        at r (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js:7:408)
        at F (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js:56:496)
        at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js:51:299)
        at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js:51:316)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IndexCtrl is undefined. To fix the error define IndexCtrl. You can't use console.debug as the call to the service will be asynchronous. For now just assign the result to scope

```
var IndexCtrl = function ($scope, Restangular){
    $scope.data = Restangular.all("data").getList().$object;
};

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('IndexCtrl', IndexCtrl);

IndexCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', "Restangular"];
```

There was also a problem with your service not being restful so I got another service url that was:

```
angular.module('app',["restangular", "ngRoute"])
.config(function (RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com');
});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6j3WPIlU9e1E5b1Mhj6g?p=preview)

Comment: There's lots of other issues. I fixed the one you posted in the question. I'd suggest you read some tutorials before posting a question like this.

Comment: please help to remove error so that i will learn I try http://goo.gl/tbVgkY ..where Is issue .could you please help me removing error

Comment: What is RestangularProvider? It's not declared anywhere?

Comment: Actually I make example after study of this tutorial http://bahmutov.calepin.co/fast-prototyping-using-restangular-and-json-server.html he used RestangularProvider

Comment: did you use restangular.js file before ? Please look on this issue

Comment: did you find anything ..any problem

Comment: You should use plunkr. It's much better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68872/discussion-between-wayne-ellery-and-user944513).

Comment: i will use could you please help me why my webservice call not work